# Integrate tables in large data frame

Tags: r, dataframe

i have three tables

the first table include ID First_date,Birthday,Sex

```
ID First_date Birthday Sex
1    19970104 19940921   M
2    19970107 19561224   F
3    20061228 19320426   M
4    20070231 19780825   F
5    20071231 19421206   F
```

second table include ID event_type event_time

```
ID  event_type  event_time
2       1        19990211     
4       1        20071226
```

third table include  ID event_type event_time

```
ID  event_type   event_time
1     2          19990219
3     2          20070228
```

and then i want be Integrate tables

```
ID   First_date Birthday Sex  event_type   event_time
1    19970104 19940921   M      2          19990219
2    19970107 19561224   F      1          19990211 
3    20061228 19320426   M      2          20070228
4    20070231 19780825   F      1          20071226
5    20071231 19421206   F      0             NA
```

the id5 did not in two and three table so the event_type will be codeing 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use `merge` here :

```
 res <- merge(dat1,rbind(dat2,dat3),all.x=TRUE)
 ID First_date Birthday Sex event_type event_time
1  1   19970104 19940921   M          2   19990219
2  2   19970107 19561224   F          1   19990211
3  3   20061228 19320426   M          2   20070228
4  4   20070231 19780825   F          1   20071226
5  5   20071231 19421206   F         NA         NA
```

Then you can assign 0 to the missed event_type :

```
res$event_type[is.na(res$event_type)] <- 0
```

here data tables are :

```
dat1 <- read.table(text='ID First_date Birthday Sex
1    19970104 19940921   M
2    19970107 19561224   F
3    20061228 19320426   M
4    20070231 19780825   F
5    20071231 19421206   F',header=TRUE)

dat2 <- read.table(text='ID  event_type  event_time
2       1        19990211     
4       1        20071226',header=TRUE)

dat3 <- read.table(text='ID  event_type   event_time
1     2          19990219
3     2          20070228',header=TRUE)
```